# javascript import, export: simple example failing

Tags: javascript, html, import, module, export

test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

auxiliary.js

```js
export let greeting = 'hello';
```

main.js

```js
import { greeting } from './auxiliary.js';

document.write(greeting);
```

In Web Console are 2 warnings:

1. Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ... (Reason: CORS request not http).
2. Module source URI is not allowed in this document: ... .

The greeting doesn't show up on the page.

EDIT:
I added curlies in the import statement, as suggested by areallytinydot and Abhinav Nigam. The warnings are still there and the page is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

The import should look like this, since it's not a default export.

```
import { greetings } from 'auxiliary.js'
```

The line `document.write(greeting)` could be causing it. If that is the case, `console.log(greeting)` should work. Could you try using this? [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

```
document.open()
document.write(greeting)
document.close()
```

Comment: I added the curlies. The warnings are still there and the page is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues here:

1. You didn't imported auxiliary.js
2. You imported greeting as a default import, instead you should import as `import { greeting } from './auxiliary.js'`

Comment: I applied the suggestion in issue #2. Could you elaborate on issue #1?

Comment: I guess you need you need to add a script tag for auxiliary.js as well.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set up a local web server (Prerequisites in the page are actually not needed to do it.):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server

This leads to this error:
`A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored.`

After changing it to console.log(), the greeting is displayed in the Web Console.